# How to add client side libraries with ReactJS.net?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-mvc, reactjs.net

I am using ReactJS.net for my .Net MVC web application.

I have seen tutorials for *reactJS* where we can install libraries with *npm*.

Similarly, I am tying to add [Tabulator](http://tabulator.info/) data table library to my application that uses ReactJS.net

I have tried adding like the following in a view file along with the react libraries:

```
<script crossorigin src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/remarkable/1.7.1/remarkable.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.6.1/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.6.1/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/React/Crud.jsx")"></script>
```

But it doesn't seem to work while I try to import it in the *jsx* file.

Any ideas on how to add libraries to ReactJS.NET.

I am trying for a solution that doesn't use *WEBPACK* or *BABEL*

Comment: did you find a solution for that?

Comment: this was an old problem, but if my memory is correct, this issue was with asp.net. My client later thought to change technology to .net core. So, I didnt find a solution for this prob. sorry.